# Centos 7 gcc 8 installation

Tags: centos, yum, gcc

GCC 8 is out for a white and I would like to test on CentOS 7, but no devtoolset-8 yet in yum.

I found https://cbs.centos.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=7198 but this is cbs; Can I have it as a nirmal yum repository?

Comment: Rather than adding it as a `yum` repo, I used `wget` to download all of the `rpm`s from here: https://cbs.centos.org/repos/sclo7-devtoolset-8-rh-candidate/x86_64/os/Packages/ into a directory and then I ran `yum install *.rpm`. I then ran `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` to change to `GCC 8`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now `devtools-8` is available and it's possible to use it by following commands:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
scl enable devtoolset-8 -- bash
```

It's explained in a little more detail in this answer on StackOverflow: [How to install GCC/G++ 8 on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345845/3801449). And of course, if you need `GFortran`, you can install it in the same way - the package is `devtoolset-8-gcc-gfortran`.